# React and setting state using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this code. I want to know how the code inside map function which is returning an array.
Hi everyone i am bit confused about the code inside the map function. Can someone explain how does returning the todo object and how its completed value is updated.

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import todosData from "./todosData"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
                if (todo.id === id) {
                    return {
                        ...todo,
                        completed: !todo.completed
                    }
                }
                return todo
            })
            console.log(prevState.todos)
            console.log(updatedTodos)
            return {
                todos: updatedTodos
            }
        })
    }
    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>)

        return (
            <div className="todo-list">
                {todoItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function is a JavaScript function which basically creates a new array that has been changed. In this case it's going over your `todos` array and appending your `TodoItem` component. For more information about the map function, read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

The code example is using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). Basically what this piece of code here does:

```
            if (todo.id === id) {
                return {
                    ...todo,
                    completed: !todo.completed
                }
            }
            return todo
```

is it does return the todo if it's id does not equal to the value inside the `id` variable.
if it todo.id does equal to `id`, you return a copy of the todo object (`{...todo}`) and you toggle the value of completed.

**Edit:**
And like A.K.M Adib explained above this statement is a javascript map function, which loops through your array and returns the value you specify in your return statement instead of the currently looped object. You could compare this with a for loop which basically sets the value of the currently looped element each time.